# Workflow for Cypress, Pharo and Amber

Tags: git, github, smalltalk, amber-smalltalk

I have a new Pharo 1.4 image setup and want to start playing around with Cypress and exporting packages to git / GitHub.

What's the best way to get started with that? FileTree?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [**FileTree**](https://github.com/dalehenrich/filetree) implements the [Cypress](https://github.com/CampSmalltalk/Cypress) package structure for Pharo and Squeak.

The [FileTree README](https://github.com/dalehenrich/filetree/blob/master/README.md) provides installations instructions.

Keep an eye on the [**amber-cypress** project](https://github.com/CampSmalltalk/amber-cypress) for an Amber implementation of the Cypress package structure.

Dale **[updated later that day....]**

Answer (score 1):

As the work turns, there is a better/alternative answer to this question:

Use [Amber Skeleton](http://gemstonesoup.wordpress.com/2012/04/22/amber-skeleton-lookout-kaliningrad/).

**Amber Skeleton** provides a project template that includes Pharo as a FileServer for Amber. There's a fair amount of [documentation for **Amber Skeleton**](https://github.com/dalehenrich/amber-skeleton/blob/master/README.md).